# PHP Excel ( PHPExcel_IOFactory ) encoding issue

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

Thanks in advance.

Im uploading a .csv file through php 5.5 script that converts it from Unicode to UTF-8 and finally saves it on a folder.

Then i read this file with PHPExcel_IOFactory and capture some data to an array. So far so good. File uploads and saves ok, but something may be messing the data in the conversion process, because im getting the text strings in the array filled with blank spaces like this:

```
array(20) {
["A"]=>
string(39) "
 l : 1 7 0 4 8 0 8 8 8 6 4 9 2 3 5 9 "
["B"]=>
string(51) " 2 0 1 7 - 0 8 - 0 9 T 0 0 : 2 1 : 5 7 + 0 2 : 0 0 "
["C"]=>
string(41) " a g : 2 3 8 4 2 6 1 5 5 8 3 3 9 0 2 5 8 "
["D"]=>
bool(false)
["E"]=>
string(41) " a s: 2 3 8 4 2 6 1 5 5 8 3 3 7 0 2 5 8"
["F"]=>
string(29) " D E S A R R O L L O  W E B "
```

Maybe its because Delimiters. Opening .csv on sublime reveals two 'white spaces' as delimiters, so if i pass something like this :

```
$objReader->setDelimiter('  ');
```

It works and reads data, but filled with empty spaces. Some tip about how to get clean data from file?

**NOTE**: Using WAMP its working ok converting the file like this:

```
$conversion = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($conversion, mb_detect_order(), 
true), "UTF-8", $conversion);
```

In production environment not working at all with that conversion (File saves empty)

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted out the problem. For anyone using PHPExcel and having same issue on character codification, if you really need to save the .xls file on a different character set, try something like this on the conversion:

```
$objReader->setDelimiter("\t");
$inputFileName = array_shift($inputFileNames); 
$conversion = file_get_contents($inputFileName); 
$conversion = iconv("WINDOWS-1252", "UTF-8", $conversion);
```

Thanks!